# Is it possible to update a nested package in package-lock.json file?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, npm

For example this make-fetch-happen package under npm/node-gyp/node_modules/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Marw5.png

I want to update this package make-fetch-happen as the http-cache-semantics v4.1.0 in here is tagged as not safe version.

Or is it possible to remove these nested folders and packages in package-lock.json file?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides).

Simple add the override inside your package.json file and run `npm install`.

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "make-fetch-happen": "10.2.1"
        ...
    },
    "overrides": {
        "make-fetch-happen": {
            "http-cache-semantics": "<version>"
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that changing the dependencies of dependencies in this way might lead to bugs and unexpected behaviour. In such cases you have to wait for an update of the package itself.